# Why is this component not showing up on my browser upon running react app?

Tags: reactjs

I'm fairly new to react and learning it atm. I am stuck at this for days now and it wont show up on my browser. Navbar works fine when I return it as JSX code only in App.js but it ain't working if I try to make it a component and then import it in [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmyAI.png)App.js[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QvOx.png)

I was trying to make component but it is not showing up on my browser

Comment: Please do not attach images of code, instead edit the question to contain a minimal reproducible example and I'm sure you will be helped swiftly! :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**Not completely sure** but I would change that folder name from My Components to My_Components or MyComponents or plain components. Always a bad idea to have spaces in folder and file names